# A Question about MIPS Instruction

Tags: mips

Hey, how to perform an arithmetic right shift in MIPS instruction set?

Comment: Your question title is very poor. "MIPS instruction set" or "MIPS left shift instruction" would be much better.

Answer (score 1):

SLL and SLLV perform **left shifts**, but the question was about **right shifts**.
SRA and SRAV perform arithmetic right shifts (with sign bit duplication).
SRL and SRLV perform logical right shifts.

Answer (score 0):

There are two instructions that do this: **SLL** and **SLLV**.

**SLL** takes a constant value (encoded in the instruction) and shifts a register by that amount.

**SLLV** shifts a register by the value stored in another register.